# Sort a Dictionary in Python Based on its Keys (when all keys are ints)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Basically, I have a dictionary where all the keys are ints where the highest keys are at the end of the list and the lower keys are at the start (sort of like a list).

Note I can't use a list for reasons I won't go into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [ordered dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) is what you are looking for.  For example

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = {4:'str1', 19:'str2', 1:'str3', 7:'str4'}
>>> orderedData = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))
>>> orderedData
OrderedDict([(1, 'str3'), (4, 'str1'), (7, 'str4'), (19, 'str2')])
```

You can still deal with an `OrderedDict` the same way you can deal with a normal dictionary, so

```
>>> orderedData[1]
'str3'
>>> orderedData[11] = 'str5'
>>> orderedData
OrderedDict([(1, 'str3'), (4, 'str1'), (7, 'str4'), (19, 'str2'), (11, 'str5')])
```

Also, this will work with any kind of key, `ints` not required.

Comment: Be aware that an `OrderedDict` sorts its members in *insertion* order.  Thus, you will not be able to put another member into it and assume it will remain sorted.